# freepbx and java server interation

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami, freepbx

I would like to do integration of freepbx and java web server.

1. There will be an IVR.
2. IVR will ask callers age
3. This age should be entered into database through some web server.

1 and 2 can be done in freepbx. 
Not sure how the data (age pressed on keyborad) will be redirected to other server.

What configuration I need to do in freepbx through admin ui? 
Do I need any specific type to server to handle request from freepbx after getting age information?

How asterisk-java will help in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have do custom programming to send info to other server.

Freepbx web not designed to do that, is is simpel dumb pbx for small offices,free one.

You CAN'T do it via GUI(except variant requesting specialized freepbx module using third-party freelancer).

If you still want do it "FreePBX way", read this materials :

- http://www.freepbx.org/trac/wiki/DevWiki
- http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/extensions_conf.html